# "Windows failed to start" error while installing from USB

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I want to install Windows 7 from a USB drive. I used Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool to move the files from the ISO file to the USB and after I insert the USB to the computer I get this message.

> **Windows Boot Manager**
>   
>     Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click "repair your computer."
>
> File: \boot\bcd
>
> Status: 0xc000000e
>
> Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

In the boot setting I set it to use the USB before the hard drive.

Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are running the Windows 7 USB installation from a USB 2.0 port.

If you try to use it from a 3.0 port similar problems to those you are experiencing may happen.

edit: usb 3.0 is usually identified by a **blue-ish color**.

[image]

Comment: how i can know if it is USB 2.0 port?